Quantum field in momentum basis for zero-mode of the sine-Gordon model
Given the sine-Gordon model where the boson field $\Phi$ is defined with compactification radius $R$
$$\begin{equation}
\Phi(L) = \Phi(0) + 2\pi Rm, \quad  m \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation}\tag{A.6}$$
The spectrum of the conjugate momentum for the zero mode is $${\Pi}_0 |\ell\rangle = \frac{\ell}{R} |\ell\rangle, \, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ The field ${\Phi}_0$ can have the Fourier expansion in terms of momentum eigenstates
\begin{equation}
    {\Phi}_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi R}} \sum_{\ell \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-i \ell {\Phi}_0 / R} |\ell\rangle,
\end{equation}
such that $$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n \Phi_0 / R}|\ell\rangle=|\ell+n\rangle.$$ However, with this definition, the canonical commutation relation $$[{\Phi}_0, {\Pi}_0]=i\tag{A.11}$$ is not fulfilled. How should ${\Phi}_0$ be defined? The zero mode is tricky since it's non-harmonic so it can't be represented in Fock basis.
A description of the model can be found in this paper (See Appendix A2).

In the Fourier expansion of $\Phi_0$ you also have $\Phi_0$ on the RHS in the exponent. What do you mean by this? More importantly, the LHS is an operator while the RHS a state. What's the correct form of this equation?

@ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Yes, the issue is that I don't know the correct form of the equation and hence the question. The motivation comes from the usual Fourier series of a periodic function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_q f_q e^{iqx}$. I'm looking for a representation of $\Phi_0$ in the momentum basis.

$\Phi_0$ does not even depend on $x$. Nothing to Fourier here.  I'd recommend OP to find a proper review/textbook on bosonization.  The appendix contains in 5 pages what other authors would spend 50 pages to review.

As @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə has pointed out, $\Phi_0$ is an operator and not a state.  The "Fourier expansion" is completely nonsense.
In equation (A18) you have already make the spatial Fourier transformation, and $\Phi_0$ is the uniform component of the angular field operator $\Phi(x)$:
$$
\Phi(x) = \Phi_0 + (\text{$x$-dependent})
$$
And a canonical momentum $\Pi_0$ conjugated to $\Phi_0$ is introduced.
Crucially, there is no spatial dependence in either $\Pi_0$ or $\Phi_0$.  As far as this pair is concerned, the model is not a QFT, but is only equivalent to single-particle QM.
Think of $\Phi_0$ as the (first quantized) position operator and $\Pi_0$ as the momentum operator of something living on a circle.  $\Pi_0$ has discrete spectrum due to periodic boundary condition.  Being multi-valued, $\Phi_0$ itself is ill-defined globally, and only periodic function of $\Phi_0$ are physically allowed.  The operator $\exp(i\Phi_0/R)$ shifts $\Pi_0$ just like $\exp(ik\hat{x})$ boosts single-particle momentum.
My previous suggestion in the comment stands: bosonization is not something to learn in 5 pages.  Try this review by Senechal.

Thank you very much for the reference! I have some follow-up questions.

It's stated that the momentum spectrum is not a simple Cartesian product (p. 14). Does that mean $\Phi_0 \neq Q \otimes \bar{Q}$?
Ultimately, I want a representation of a single-mode squeezing operator for the zero mode, defined in a manner analogous to the two-mode squeezing operator $\hat{S}(\xi_k) = \exp{[\xi_k(A_{-k}A_{+k} - A^\dagger_{+k}A^{\dagger}_{-k})]}$. How can this be done given $\Phi_0$ and $\Pi_0$? Do you have some suggestions or references on this topic?


(1) What is not a product of what?  What are $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$?  I can't seem to find anything related to your question on p.14. (2) Not happening.  You can't do two-mode-anything with only one mode.  Sorry I can't be of more help; I only know a bit about bosonization, but nothing on tensor network and quantum simulation.

(1) The left zero-mode $Q$ and the right zero-mode $\bar{Q}$ are in Eq. (50) (at the end of section 5.1). I mean can the boson field for the zero mode $\Phi_0$ be written as a tensor product of  $Q$  and $\bar{Q}$? (2) I think the tensor network aspect is irrelevant because you can have a squeeze operator for a single mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator).

Why would any field operators be written as the product of left and right chiral modes?  You must mean the sum.  If you are very sure you want a product, please read the review and learn that $\Phi_0$ isn't want you think it is.

Now let's talk the sum scenario.  The whole point is there is only one zero mode, and not enough degrees of freedom to be split into two chiral modes!  It is possible to introduce another operator $r$ conjugated to the winding number $w$, and the pair $\lbrace r, w\rbrace$ furnishes another set of ladder operators at zero momentum.   So now you have enough stuff going around to make two chiral modes.  This amounts to inserting (singular) instantons by hand, and should be justified by the physics underneath the model.  See Senechel.
